# How to filter multiple nested array object by using multi nested objects using aggregate in mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to filter multiple nested array object by using multi nested objects in aggregate using mongoose nodejs. I have mention sample record data from collection and multi filter objects.

I work with one e-commerce product listing view page. In this listing page we have lot of products with different kind of features. Here I need to filter that products by using that list of product feature.

**Example:**

> I have 3 number of mobile phones with different kind of features, like
>   Color, RAM, Storage. These features are placed inside "productfilter"
>   array in the below sample collection record. I could selected multiple
>   features to filter mobile phones like, i select color: Blue, gold and
>   RAM: 6GB, 8GB. Here second product from sample product list data, need
>   to get as per selected filter. Because color:Blue and RAM:6GB is
>   matched along with "IsDefault: 'true'" in second product object from
>   sample product list data
>
> Here need to filter records based on filter request data and along  with that need to check "isDefault" to be "true"

**Sample collection records**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d710f9950b94f237f04407b",
    "productfilter": [
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0799",
        "specTitle": "Color",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079d",
            "specLabel": "Rose Gold",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-rose-gold-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079c",
            "specLabel": "Black",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-black-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079b",
            "specLabel": "Blue",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-blue-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079a",
            "specLabel": "Red",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-red-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0796",
        "specTitle": "RAM",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0798",
            "specLabel": "4GB",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-black-4gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0797",
            "specLabel": "6GB",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-black-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0794",
        "specTitle": "Storage",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de0795",
            "specLabel": "64GB",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d710fe050b94f237f04407e",
    "productfilter": [
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a3",
        "specTitle": "Color",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a7",
            "specLabel": "Rose Gold",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-rose-gold-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a6",
            "specLabel": "Black",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-black-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a5",
            "specLabel": "Blue",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-blue-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a4",
            "specLabel": "Red",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-red-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a0",
        "specTitle": "RAM",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a2",
            "specLabel": "4GB",
            "isDefault": "false",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-blue-4gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de07a1",
            "specLabel": "6GB",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": "mobiles-accessories-mobiles-redmi-redmi-redmi-note-6-pro-blue-6gb-64gb-redmi-note-6-pro"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079e",
        "specTitle": "Storage",
        "attributeOptions": [
          {
            "_id": "5d8d29ae014da910c0de079f",
            "specLabel": "64GB",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "specContent": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Sample selected request data from filter option lists in product list view pages, to filter above records**

```
{
  "filter": {
    "genericFilter": [
      {
        "specTitle": "Color",
        "specLabel": [
          "Blue",
          "Gold",
          "Rose Gold"
        ]
      },
      {
        "specTitle": "RAM",
        "specLabel": [
          "6GB",
          "8GB"
        ]
      },
      {
        "specTitle": "Storage",
        "specLabel": [
          "64GB",
          "256GB"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @uday-s this not really that clear. Provide a better description

Comment: I have update the detailed description. Can you check it

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) as following

```
db.products.aggregate([
   {
        $unwind: "$productfilter"
   },
   {
        $unwind: "$productfilter.attributeOptions"
   },
   {
       $project: {
           "specTitle": "$productfilter.specTitle",
           "specLabel": "$productfilter.attributeOptions.specLabel",
           "isDefault": "$productfilter.attributeOptions.isDefault",
           _id:0
       }
   },
   {
       $group: {
           "_id": "$specTitle",
           "specLabel": {$addToSet: "$specLabel"}
       }
   },
   {
    $project: {
        "specTitle": "$_id",
        "specLabel": "$specLabel",
        "isDefault": "$productfilter.attributeOptions.isDefault",
        _id:0
    }
   },
])
```

**Explanation:**

1. In first stage, the query [unwinds](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) the array `productFilter`; it means dividing the document in multiple records for each value of `productFilter` array item
2. In second stage it does the same for `attributeOptions` which was inside `productFilter`
3. [Project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) stage, keeps the relevant fields from the document and names them for later purpose
4. [Groups](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) all documents now by `specTitle` and creates a new field 'specLabel'(which utilizes [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to make an array from all different 'specLabel' values.). As it's a set, it does not repeat the values if it's present.
5. Finally restructures the document as wanted. (Here I haven't included filters, genericFilter as per sample result because they are redundant but if you want, you can just edit the last stage `$project` to suit your needs

Comment: @uday-s does this solve the problem for you?
Upvote if this answer helps you solve the problem. Accept answer if it is correct answer to the problem.